# Running docker project got "Error response from daemon: readlink ..." error

Tags: docker

Under kubuntu 22 I try to run old docker project, but I got error :

```
master@master-at-home:/_wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/__DOCKER$ docker compose up -d --build
Error response from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/NZKFX3UQ2GCYOP22Q6SO2TJX7A: no such file or directory
```

What I have now in my OS :

```
$  lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
6.2.0-35-generic
x86_64
master@master-at-home:/_wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/__DOCKER$ dpkg -s   docker
dpkg-query: package 'docker' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
master@master-at-home:/_wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/__DOCKER$ dpkg -s  docker-compose-plugin
Package: docker-compose-plugin
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 59356
Maintainer: Docker <support@docker.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: docker-ce (5:24.0.6-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy)
Version: 2.21.0-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy
Enhances: docker-ce-cli
Description: Docker Compose (V2) plugin for the Docker CLI.
 .
 This plugin provides the 'docker compose' subcommand.
 .
 The binary can also be run standalone as a direct replacement for
 Docker Compose V1 ('docker-compose').
Homepage: https://github.com/docker/compose
master@master-at-home:/_wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/__DOCKER$ dpkg -s  docker-buildx-plugin
Package: docker-buildx-plugin
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 76085
Maintainer: Docker <support@docker.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: docker-ce (5:24.0.5-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy)
Version: 0.11.2-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy
Replaces: docker-ce-cli
Enhances: docker-ce-cli
Description: Docker Buildx cli plugin.
Homepage: https://github.com/docker/buildx
```

How to fix error anf=d to run the project ?